# How can I set the "target" attribute of <a> tags which are already "embedded" into HTML?

Tags: html, vue.js, kentico, vue-directives, kentico-kontent

I am developing a website using VueJS, and Kentico Kontent as a CMS. This CMS offers the "rich text" feature, basically allowing text content to embed links and basic formatting, which gets automatically converted into HTML when served through the API.

I have no problem displaying the HTML content using the `v-html` directive, but I cannot think of a way to set the attributes of the inner `<a>` tags to `_blank`, so that the embedded links open new windows when clicked.

Is there any elegant way to do this without having to parse the HTML from the Front-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a directive:

```
Vue.directive('links-in-new-window', {
  inserted: function(el) {
    const anchors = el.querySelectorAll('a')

    anchors.forEach((anchor) => anchor.target = "_blank")
  }

})
```

And just apply that to the same element you're using the `v-html` on:

```
<div class="content" v-html="content" v-links-in-new-window></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In vue V3 the directive would look like this:

```
app.directive('links-in-new-window', {
  mounted: function(el) {
    const anchors = el.querySelectorAll('a')
    anchors.forEach((anchor) => anchor.target = "_blank")
  }
})
```

HTML is the same, remember to use `v-` => `v-links-in-new-window`

```
<div class="content" v-html="content" v-links-in-new-window></div>
```